# How would I add a border-radius to only the start and end of my li navbar?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a navigation bar for my site and I want the corners on the top left, bottom left, top right, and bottom right to be curved. I know how to use border-radius, but if I use it on the navbar it has a curved corners on each link. How would I have the curved corners on just the start and the end? [Slightly like these.](http://images.colourbox.com/thumb_COLOURBOX3891330.jpg)

Here is my HTML

```html
<body>

<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Header">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><img src="Text-Align.png">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="Text-Align.png">Bins</a></li>  
            <li><a href=""><img src="Text-Align.png">Kidzone</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="Text-Align.png">Why?</a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="Text-Align.png">How?</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Here is my CSS

```css
html{
    background-color:#E4E4E4;
}

body,html{
    margin-top: 0px;
    height:100%;
}

#Wrapper{
    display:block;
    background-color: white;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-color:#B8B8B8;
    border-left-width:1px;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-right-color:#B8B8B8;
    border-right-width:1px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#Header{
    width:800px;
    margin-left:35px;
}

#Header ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
}

#Header li{
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-left-width:1px;  
    border-left-color:white;
    display:block;
    width:145px;
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
}


a:link,a:visited{
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url("navbar.gif");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
    color:white;
}

a:hover,a:active{
    background-image:url("navbarhover.gif");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `border-radius` in use at all here. Are we supposed to guess what "I use it on the navbar" means?

Comment: You can achieve this by using the `:first-child` and `:last-child` (which will only match the first and last element) pseudo selectors, but these one won't work in IE<9.

Comment: Did you try using border-radius on the ul level and not the li's? 
Like `#Header ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    border-radius:10px;
}`

Comment: @JohannesKlauß: Actually `:first-child` is supported by IE 7 +

Answer (score 3):

If you can use CSS3, then you can use the `first` and `last` pseudo selectors.

```css
#Header ul li:first-child {

}

#Header ul li:last-child {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make an id tag in your styles with this:

```
border-top-left-radius: Xpx;
border-bottom-left-radius: Xpx;
```

defined, and define the id on the li's you want,so the top and bottom one's, and change the Xpx to what you want

Answer (score 0):

why not use border-radius on UL ?
http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/vwwLb/1/

```css
#Header ul {
    list-style: none;/* this to wrap floatting elements */
    display: inline-block;
    background:blue linear-gradient(0deg,transparent,#eee,transparent);
    padding:0 2em;
    margin:0;
    border-radius:1em;
}
```